# Android (App)Widget identification

Tags: android

Im writing little widget that shows time, date.. with many settings. And I want to have multiple instances of this widget with diferent settings. 
Is there any way to identify widget instance. I mean is it posible to set persistant id on witget instance so Ill know on update that I have to use setting for for example witget one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.

if you read the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring you'll see many references to mAppWidgetId/appWidgetIds/etc.  This is a unique Id per instance of your widget.  you can associate this Id with your configuration info.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider a configuration activity that will launch every time an instance of your widget is created, you can configure what time (or) details the user wants on the screen.